# Automated migrations for Azure Blob Storage. Does this exist?

Tags: azure, migration, azure-storage

We are using Azure Blob Storage in all our projects. Through lifetime of a project the naming convention for files in Azure change: sometimes we would like to rename containers, remove extra folders and other clean-up operations.
But Azure does not allow easily to rename things, we have to do copy-delete.

Also we can change naming convention locally, during development. But we need to remember do the exact operation on production storage when we deploy new versions.

At the same time we use Entity Framework migrations: we updated database, migration script is created. Then we run "update-database" and DB is updated. The same is run automatically by deployment scripts: check if production DB needs to be updated, and update it if needed.

What would be good if we can do the same migration goodness for Azure storage: check if all the migration scripts have been applied, execute processes for missing scripts. Somewhere in the containers keep a reference to a latest executed script.

Does such thing exist? or should I have a go on it and try implementing something myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such functionality/behavior does not exists. And do remember that EF migrations are supported and are part of the EF itself, not the Data Base! So when you talk about Azure Blob Storage - it, as a service does not provide such functionality, the same way SQL Server itself does not do it.

To the question if such a library/code exists - no there isn't.

You are raising a very interesting question though!

I personally am not a big fan of "migrations". You can do it while in early stages of development life cycle. But once you hit GA/Production, you have to be very careful what you are doing. Even EF migrations might be good with small database sizes, but are you willing to run migrations on a DB which has tables with millions of records production data? Same with blobs. If you have 100 or 1000 blobs might be fine. How about 2M blobs? Are you really willing to put some code that would go through 2M entities and do some operations over it, and run this code as part of your build/deploy process? I would not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that SQL Server does not support migrations naitively. EF provides scripting and checking for versions. I was hoping to find library that could help with this. And as production goes, I'd rather write a script to do automatic migration for 2M blobs (and test the hell out of it) rather then do that manually. But not really running it automatically as part of deployment process.

Comment: And I would rather focus on versioning strategy, rather than migrating 2M blobs (might be 2T, then what?). Just to speculate a bit - probably a meta data such as "version" would help my library to determine the concrete naming convention for concrete blob. Even more, I would save blob absolute URI in a relevant storage to have it handy, rather then relying on naming convention to find out what is the actual name/location of a blob. Not to mention that large scale system on Azure usually work with multiple storage accounts, which will vastly increase the complexity of your script.

Comment: That is an interesting point about versioning. We have tried keeping urls for blobs in DB and it turned out not so good for our purposes. But I see your point, no need to put wasts of time into such migration library - it is probably not going to be used.